# Sass/Sprockets: Where is image-url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm currently implementing a runtime module which creates a sass file, generates a css file from it, removes the sass and gets on with its life. I'm on Rails on Sprockets. I've been meddling with the internals, and discovered its static_compiler class. So, what I'm doing, step by step, is:

1. Generating Sass Files and Sprites
2. Instantiating a static compiler
3. Using the compiler to generate the css and sprites with the digest keys

Now, I'm having a hard time with the sass "image-url" method and pngs. I'm using it on the sass files like this:

```
image-url("image.png")
image-url("image.svg")
```

which points to the right sub-directory under app/assets. The name of the digested image.svg file is rightly generated, that is, the digest key on the css file matches the digest key from the file. But the same is not happening with the png, the digest key from the css file doesn't match the digest key from file. I'm having a hard time debugging this, because it is not very clear where the "image-url" helper is declared. Does anybody know why this only happens to pngs and/or where is the image-url method defined? (I'm only aware it is not a sass file, so it must be a rails dependency).

EDIT:

This is a sample of my script:

```
bundled_sass = Sprockets::BundledAsset.new(Rails.application.assets, "random_name.css", sassfile_path)
bundled_svg = Sprockets::StaticAsset.new(Rails.application.assets, "sprite.svg", svgfile_path)
bundled_png = Sprockets::StaticAsset.new(Rails.application.assets, "sprite.png", pngfile_path)
compiler = Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(Rails.application.assets,
                               destination_path,
                               Rails.application.config.assets.precompile,
                               #:manifest_path => Rails.application.config.assets.manifest,
                               :digest => Rails.application.config.assets.digest,
                               :manifest => true)
compiler.write_asset(bundled_svg)
compiler.write_asset(bundled_png)
compiler.write_asset(bundled_sass)
```

with config.assets.digest option set to true, the svg and png are copied to the destination_path folder (usually public/assets) and their names get a digest key. When the sass file is compiled, the key generated for the svg url is the right one. The digest key used for the png url differs from the one on the file.

Comment: A `image-url()` function is included with Compass, are you sure you're not supposed to be getting it from there?

Comment: yes, because i'm not using compass.

Comment: agree with comment from cimmanon. when you grep over sprockets for "_url", "image", "-url", there seems to be no image-url included in sprockets, so, why do you think it's sprockets related?

Comment: because if I use the Sass engine to compile the code, I get an error there. It is not necessarily defined in Sprockets, but its resource do include rails-specific helpers which had certain functions to the Sass script which would otherwise not be defined.